# Is there a way I can read all the messages in the rabbitmq queue from a script, while the messages are consumed by a consumer script?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, rabbitmq

I have a system, where I use rabbitmq as a broker to do a remote procedure call. Now multiple requests can be sent to the queue so I am looking to implement a way using logs/data which records how long a particular requests takes so before sending a request the remote user will request using an API call to get the wait time and based on that send a request to the broker. So I am trying to build a server which can read all the rabbitmq messages waiting in the queue to be consumed using python. I want to read all the payload in the queue using python.

System:
I'm using Docker to run rabbitmq server.
User sends request to an IP address, which is the remote host running the rabbitmq server and my consumer script.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

I was able to read all the messages from the UI web interface, I even tried listing queue from rabbitmqctl list_queue command but it can only get the number of messages and not the payload.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = f"http://{host}:{port}/api/queues/%2F/rpc_queue/get"

payload = {
    "count":100,
    "ackmode":"ack_requeue_true",
    "encoding":"auto",
    "truncate":50000
}

r = requests.post(url, auth=(username, passwd), json=payload)
```

Refer the documentation here: [https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/v3.11.9/deps/rabbitmq_management/priv/www/api/index.html#:~:text=/api/queues/vhost/name/get](https://rawcdn.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/v3.11.9/deps/rabbitmq_management/priv/www/api/index.html#:%7E:text=/api/queues/vhost/name/get)